# Integrating Factor for Vorticity Evolution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, integrating-factor

The Vorticity Evolution in 2D Cartesian Coordinates, assuming incompressibility, is as follows:
$$ \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t} = \nu \left( \frac{\partial^2 \omega}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \omega}{\partial y^2} \right) - \left( u \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y} \right)  $$
By using discrete spectral methods, assuming periodic boundary conditions, where  $\Omega_{pq} = \mathrm{fft2}(\omega_{ij})$, our equation becomes:
$$ \frac{\partial \Omega_{pq}}{\partial t} = \nu \left( \frac{\partial^2 \Omega_{pq}}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \Omega_{pq}}{\partial y^2} \right) - \mathrm{fft2} \left(  u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right) $$

If we replace the derivative operator with spectral derivatives ($ \partial / \partial x = + \underline{i} k_p$), we obtain the following:
$$ \frac{\partial \Omega_{pq}}{\partial t} = - \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) \Omega_{pq} - \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right) $$
I have been given the following equation, which claims to be equivalent to those above, where $\Xi_{pq} = \exp \left[ \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) t \right]$ is an integrating factor:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \Xi_{pq} \Omega_{pq} \Big] = -\underline{i} \Xi_{pq} \Big[ k_p \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left(u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right) + k_q \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( v_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right) \Big]$$

Unfortunately, I don't understand how these are equivalent, though a numerical simulation with Python seems to show agreement. To aid those that don't recognize what these variables represent and the relations between them, the following relations are true by definition:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2} = - \omega \quad \to \quad \Psi_{pq} = \frac{\Omega_{pq}}{k_p^2 + k_q^2} $$
$$ u = +\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y} \quad \to \quad U_{pq} = + \underline{i} k_q \Psi_\mathrm{pq} = + \frac{\underline{i} k_q \Omega_\mathrm{pq}}{k_p^2 + k_q^2} $$
$$  v_\mathrm{ij} = - \frac{\partial \psi_\mathrm{ij}}{\partial x} \quad \to \quad V_\mathrm{pq} = - \underline{i} k_p \Psi_\mathrm{pq} = - \frac{\underline{i} k_p \Omega_\mathrm{pq}}{k_p^2 + k_q^2} $$
$$  \nabla \times \vec{u} = \Big \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \Big \rangle \times \langle u, v \rangle = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \omega $$
$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{u} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$$

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense, applying the integrating factor or the modification to the nonlinearity in the equation after the sentence 'which claims to be equivalent to those above'?

Comment: @MatthewCassell, well it would be non-linear by default, so I'm not really worried about that. I'm just not really sure how Equation (4) is equivalent to (1)-(3). It seems to have the form of an integrating factor:
$$  \frac{dy}{dx} + P(x) y = Q(x) \quad \to  \quad \frac{d}{dx} \left[\mu(x) \cdot y \right] = Q(x) \cdot \mu(x) \quad \mathrm{where} \quad \mu(x) = \exp \left[ \int P(x) \, dx \right] $$
But even after differentiating out, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Yes but _what about it doesn't seem to make sense_? Perhaps I'll just show the calculation. With $\text{NL}$ the nonlinear terms and noting that $$\nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) \Xi_{pq} = \partial_{t} \Xi_{pq}$$ you have \begin{align}
\implies \frac{\partial \Omega_{pq}}{\partial t}+\nu (k_p^2 + k_q^2) \Omega_{pq} &=  - \text{NL} \\
\implies \Xi_{pq} \frac{\partial \Omega_{pq}}{\partial t}+\nu (k_p^2 + k_q^2) \Xi_{pq} \Omega_{pq} &= - \Xi_{pq} \text{NL} \\
\implies \frac{\partial (\Xi_{pq} \Omega_{pq})}{\partial t} &= - \Xi_{pq} \text{NL}
\end{align}

Comment: @MatthewCassell, I agree with your work, but how is the RHS of your final equation equation equivalent to that of my Equation (4).

$$ - \Xi_{pq} \mathrm{NL} = -\Xi_{pq} \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left[ u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right] \neq - \underline{i} \Xi_{pq} \Big[ k_p \cdot \mathrm{fft2}(u_{ij} \omega_{ij}) + k_q \cdot \mathrm{fft2}(v_{ij} \omega_{ij}) \Big] $$

Comment: I asked you in my original comment if that was the issue and you said you were not really worried about that. We could have saved ourselves a lot of time here if you had clarified the issue. Using the incompressibility condition $u_{x} + v_{y} = 0$, the nonlinear term can be written as $$u \omega_{x} + v \omega_{y} = (u \omega)_{x} + (v \omega)_{y} - \omega (u_{x} + v_{y}) = (u \omega)_{x} + (v \omega)_{y}$$ Taking the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ yields $$\mathcal{F}((u \omega)_{x} + (v \omega)_{y}) = -i [k_{p} \mathcal{F}(u \omega) + k_{q} \mathcal{F}(v \omega)]$$ which is the RHS.

Comment: @MatthewCassell, I appreciate it. That makes sense. I understood your original comment. If you write it into an answer, I will accept it. Unfortunately, "\mathcal{f}" doesn't work on Math SE.

Comment: Might I suggest you write up the answer yourself, showing all the details, and then accept your own answer. That way you can demonstrate your own understanding of the problem, as well as possibly gaining some reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the following:
$$ \frac{\partial \Omega_{pq}}{\partial t} = - \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) \Omega_{pq} - \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right) $$
$$ \implies \frac{\partial \Omega_{pq}}{\partial t} + \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) \Omega_{pq} = - \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right) $$
It can be seen that $ \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) \exp \left( \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) t \right) = \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \exp \left( \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) t \right) \right] $ by the Chain Rule, and as a result:
$$ \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \exp \left[ \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) t \right] \cdot \Omega_{pq} \Big] = - \exp \left[ \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) t \right] \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right)$$
$$ \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \Xi_{pq} \cdot \Omega_{pq}\Big] = - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right) \;\: \mathrm{where} \; \: \Xi_{pq} = \exp \left[ \nu \left( k_p^2 + k_q^2 \right) t \right] $$
Since the Fourier Transform is linear, i.e. $\mathrm{fft2}[a + b] = \mathrm{fft2}[a] + \mathrm{fft2}[b]$, we can seperate the RHS:
$$ \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \Xi_{pq} \cdot \Omega_{pq}\Big] = - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} \right) - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} \right) $$
One might be tempted to expand out the spectral derivatives for each $\omega_{ij}$ derivative, but this is invalid due to the non-linear terms the separated fourier transforms are acting on. As a result, we have to use one of the initial assumptions of incompressibility, where:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{u}_{ij} = 0 \to \frac{\partial u_{ij}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v_{ij}}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$ u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] - \frac{\partial u_{ij}}{\partial x} \omega_{ij} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ v_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] - \frac{\partial v_{ij}}{\partial y} \omega_{ij} $$
$$ \implies u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ v_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] - \omega_{ij} \left[ \frac{\partial u_{ij}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v_{ij}}{\partial y} \right] $$ $$ \implies u_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial x} + v_{ij} \frac{\partial \omega_{ij}}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ v_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] $$
Going back to the actual equation:
$$ \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \Xi_{pq} \cdot \Omega_{pq}\Big] = - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ v_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] \right) $$
$$ \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \Xi_{pq} \cdot \Omega_{pq}\Big] = - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] \right) - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ v_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right] \right) $$
$$ \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \Xi_{pq} \cdot \Omega_{pq}\Big] = - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \underline{i} k_p \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right) - \Xi_{pq} \cdot \underline{i} k_q \mathrm{fft2} \left(v_{ij} \omega_{ij}\right) $$
And now we arrive at the originally claimed equivalent form:
$$ \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big[ \Xi_{pq} \cdot \Omega_{pq}\Big] = - \underline{i} \Xi_{pq} \cdot \Big[ k_p \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left( u_{ij} \omega_{ij} \right) + k_q \cdot \mathrm{fft2} \left(v_{ij} \omega_{ij}\right) \Big] \;\: \square $$

Thank you @MatthewCassell for your help in the comments.